# Should I provide interview feedback to HR regarding their questions?

Tags: interviewing, feedback

During an interview, it is not uncommon for an HR to use questions that come from Googling.

- Some of those quesitons are so famous that it is pointless to ask them in an interview. E.g. how many fuel stations you need to build in a city?

When asked, should I point this out?

Comment: You want to tell them they asked a pointless question? How do you **think** that will go?

Comment: Why do you want to do that?

Comment: Think about it this way, what about the questions **you** ask? "What's the culture?" "Do you like your job?" "Where do you expect me to be in 30 days?" "What the room for growth?" HR has heard it all before as well - most of them from Google too.

Comment: Well, you could point it out, but that would burn the bridges with that employer's HR...  You could as well try to answer, or just tell you have no idea, and whatever the outcome of the interview is decide that you don't work for a company asking such questions. I mean, the hiring process is also somehow for you to see if you would fit in the company culture...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No (No mater if you participate as being interviewed or as another interviewer). It is not your function to correct your HR. such questions actually have several functions

- checking how well the candidate actually prepared for the interview
- checking if candidate has an original or good approach to that question
- checking how reacts to a question which he/she considers too simple
- seeing how he/she explains an approach to a non-specialist

While i am also not a friend of some HR people trying to act like they could asses how smart a candidate is by such questions, just let them play theirs games, they are probably aware that the question is well known.